# msql insert data into table based on values in two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, outer-join

I am using MySQL and have a table (documentShips) that I want to store connections / links between documents and users.

- The users table has columns including id, first_name and last_name etc...
- The documents table has columns including id and users, where the users column contains a comma separated value

  - E.g. "Joe Bloggs, Fred Nerk, Simon McCool" etc...

I want to match users between the tables (documents and users) using a like statement, e.g.:

```
where documents.authors like '% users.last_name %'
```

and insert them into the documentShips table, e.g.:

```
insert into documentShips (user_id, document_id) ... values () ... where ...
```

I am struggling to create a valid (mysql) insert statement to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!!

Thanks,
Jon.

Comment: syntex is Insert Into documentShips (id,..) select @id.. where condition. if you are using values i dont think you can use where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can use `FIND_IN_SET()` like this

```
INSERT INTO documentShips (user_id, document_id)
SELECT u.id, d.id 
  FROM documents d JOIN users u
    ON FIND_IN_SET(CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name), d.authors) > 0
 ORDER  BY d.id, u.id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/411b9/1)** demo

In order for it to work correctly you have to make sure that comma separated values in `document.authors` have no spaces before or after commas. If in fact you have spaces then eliminate them first with a query like this

```
UPDATE documents
   SET authors = REPLACE(REPLACE(authors, ' ,', ','), ', ', ',');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cade3/1)** demo

Now consider to **normalize** your `documents` table.

Answer (score 0):

Use [INSERT...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) syntax as shown in the MySQL documentation. The documentation also has some examples.